# Preventing parent state from reloading on child state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a tabbed interface akin to this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/14/deep-linking-a-tabbed-ui-with-angularjs.aspx

However, on my state change, the controller of the parent state seems to be reinitialized (or a new $scope is created?)

There are two major differences between the example plunkr and my project.

1. I use a parameter in my url
2. I resolve different data on the state change for each tab (removing this does nothing).
3. I am not using ui-bootstrap for the tabs but am triggering a $state.go on ng-click of the tab.

I experimented with the above plunkr and added a dropdown to the parent state; however the parent dropdown values seem to persist when the child states change. I am not too concerned with the child states and will probably end up using sticky states anyways.

I am using wondering if I am doing something fundamentally wrong before I try and add another package to my project.

here is a rough plunkr of what I am trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/TmRQN5K8OEc8vHG84G5z?p=preview

here is my config:

```
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.when('/main',
            function ($state) {

                $state.go('parent.tab1', { main_id: '00008' });
            });



            $stateProvider
            //Handle States Here 
            .state('parent', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/parent?main_id',
                templateUrl: "main.html",
                controller: 'Main_Controller',
                resolve: {
                                //Calls to API
                }


            })


        .state('parent.tab1', {
            url: "/applications",
            templateUrl: "tab1.html",
            controller:'Tab1Ctrl',           
            resolve: {
              //Get some different data from an API
                 },
            })


        .state('parent.tab2', {
            url: "/phasing",
            templateUrl: "tab2.html",
            controller: 'Tab2Ctrl',
            resolve: {
               //More API Data
                }
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made your [plunker working here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YeCt5VhFmj6TCfmvUBet?p=preview)

```
$urlRouterProvider
    //.when('/main',
    .when('',
    function ($state) {

        $state.go('parent.tab1', { main_id: '00008' })
    });
```

Also there is a change in main.html, which does not use *`ng-controller`* any more. We just have to pass the proper Controller name

```
$stateProvider
//Handle States Here 
.state('parent', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/parent?main_id',
  templateUrl: "main.html",
  controller: 'MainController',
  resolve: {
    //Calls to API
  }
})
...
// MainController
// these two names should fit
app.controller("MainController", function($rootScope, $scope, $state) {
```

So now, it is working, and let's discuss

1. I use a parameter in my url
2. I resolve different data on the state change for each tab (removing this does nothing).
3. I am not using ui-bootstrap for the tabs but am triggering a $state.go on ng-click of the tab.

Quick answers:

1. parameter in url exists, e.g. #/parent/tab1?main_id=8000
2. resolve is trigerred for each controller if controller is reinstantiated. That happens when we navigate to that state (among tabs)
3. no need to use $state.go, I used:

*a snippet:*

```
<a ui-sref="parent.tab1({main_id:'00008'})"> go to tab1 with main_id '00008'</a><br />
<a ui-sref="parent.tab2({main_id:'00008'})"> go to tab2 with main_id '00008'</a><br />
<a ui-sref="parent.tab3({main_id:'00008'})"> go to tab3 with main_id '00008'</a><br />
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YeCt5VhFmj6TCfmvUBet?p=preview)